# Webservice problem in C#.net

Tags: c#, webservice-client

I am creating web service for getting the employee details in client application. To achieve this i have followed the following steps:

employee propertyclass:

```
public class EmployeeProperty
{
    #region class Members.
    private string _employeeid;
    private string _employeename;   
    #endregion

    #region class property.

    public string EmployeeID
    {
      get { return _employeeid; }
      set { _employeeid = value; }
    }

    public string EmployeeName
    {
      get { return _employeename; }
      set { _employeename = value; }
    }
```

EmployeeDAL class:

```
public DataSet GetEmployeeById(EmployeeProperty employee)
{
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);    
  conn.Open();   

  // building the command
  SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("GetEmployeeById", conn);
  oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  // Parameters 
  SqlParameter paraemployeeId = new SqlParameter();
  paraemployeeId.ParameterName = "@employeeId";
  paraemployeeId.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
  paraemployeeId.Size = 15;
  paraemployeeId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  paraemployeeId.Value = employee.EmployeeID;
  oCommand.Parameters.Add(paraemployeeId);

  // Adapter and DataSet
  SqlDataAdapter oAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

  oAdapter.SelectCommand = oCommand;
  DataSet oDataSet = new DataSet();

  try
  {       
    oAdapter.Fill(oDataSet, "Employee");

    if (oDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
      employee.EmployeeID = oDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Emp_ID"].ToString();
      employee.EmployeeName = oDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Emp_Name"].ToString();         
      return oDataSet;
    }
    else
    {
      throw new ApplicationException("Business object not found.");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception oException)
  {       
    throw;
  }
  finally
  {
    conn.Close();
  }
}
```

WebserviceClass:

```
public class EmployeeWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

[Webmethod]
public DataSet GetEmployeeById(EmployeeProperty employee)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    EmployeeDAL empdal=new EmployeeDAL();
    return empdal.GetEmployeeById(employee);
}
}
```

From Client Application:

```
    webservice .EmployeeWebService empweb = new webservice .EmployeeWebService();       

    EmployeeProperty empproperty = new EmployeeProperty();         

    string empid = Txtempid.Text;

    empproperty.EmpID = empid;

    empweb.GetEmployeeById(empproperty);

    Txtempid.Text = empproperty.EmployeeID;

    Txtempname.Text = empproperty.EmployeeName;

    ....like this other values should display…..but not displaying the employee name in the text box its showing empty   value...

   What i done is correct????pls help its not working...how can i achieve it.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `DataSet` returned by the WS.

```
empweb.GetEmployeeById(empproperty);
```

The above line returns a `DataSet` containing the queried data.

Comment: Ok u mean to say ds=empweb.GetEmployeeById(empproperty); then how can populate the employeeproperty class member here..for example to display empname txtempname.text=ds.EmpName....how can i do this???

Comment: dataset.tables("tablename").rows(0).item("FieldName").tostring

Comment: txtEmpname.Tex=ds.tables[0].Rows[0]["EmployeeName"].Tostring(); its displaying but i dont want in this way
empname property automatically should poup.Any help pls??

Comment: ->PradeepGB: that i know, anyway thanks for replying..pls read my current comments, i am looking for some alternative way